# React Functional Component - Binding handler to an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to bind a handler to an array position that prints the state of the object. The function is being called but the state is always in the initial state.

```
import React from "react";

export default function MyForm() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    buttons: [],
    object: null
  });
  const stateRef = React.useRef(null);
  const onExecButtonHandler = (index) => {
    console.log("[MyForm][execButton]: " + index);
    alert(JSON.stringify(state.object));
    alert(JSON.stringify(stateRef.current.object));
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (event)=>{
    let obj = state.object
    obj['description'] = event.target.value
    console.log(obj)
    setState((state) => ({ ...state, object: obj }));
    stateRef.current = state;
  }

  const generateButtons = () => {
    let buttons = [];
    //buttons.push([name,(event)=>onExecButtonHandler(event,i),obj[i].icon,obj[i].jsFunction])
    buttons.push([
      "Show Hi",
      onExecButtonHandler.bind(this, 1),
      "icon",
      "custom function"
    ]);
    return buttons;
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[MyForm][useEffect]");

    let buttons = generateButtons();
    setState({ buttons: buttons, object: { description: "hi" } });
    stateRef.current = state;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {state.object && (
        <form>
          <input text="text" onChange={onChangeHandler} value={state.object.description} />
          <input
            type="button"
            value="Click me"
            onClick={() => {
              state.buttons[0][1]();
            }}
          />
        </form>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

You can test here: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-robinson-g1yuo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I was able to access the latest state of the object using the "useRef" hook. I'd like to access using the state though. Is there some way to do so?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why are you saving buttons in state. Also how are you using buttons from state to render and update the deps array of useEffect in the post

Comment: Sure, I have that a list of buttons because my buttons' functions will be parsed from a string in the runtime. I will basically receive a json with all form settings.

Comment: Could you add the end of the code because your useEffect function is missing closing bracket ?

Comment: Just updated the example with one that you can run :)

Comment: Added a link where you can see the same example : https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-robinson-g1yuo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark